# const BYTE * and const LPBYTE

Tags: c++, c, winapi, types

It seems that there's a difference between 'const BYTE*' & 'const LPBYTE', when i compile the folowing code (just an example):

```
void Test(const BYTE * c,const LPBYTE d) {
 c++; // OK
*c++; // OK
 d++; // ERROR
*d++; // ERROR
```

}

I get "you cannot assign to a variable that is const" on visual studio, i tried it on codeblocks and i got "increment of read-only parameter 'd'". I also used `typedef BYTE* bytes` but got the same error.

So whats going on here,Why i can modify the 'c' but not 'd' ?

Comment: `const LPBYTE d` and _'you cannot assign to a variable that is const'_ Is a pretty clear message, so what's your concern?

Comment: Why does it work with 'c' but not with 'd' ?

Comment: `*d++` tries to increment the **contents** of `d`, while this is forbidden because its declared `const`!

Comment: Doesn't *c++ increment the contents too ?

Comment: @HMVC: It does, but `c` is *not* constant, while `d` *is* constant. This is why `d++` does not compile, while `c++` compiles. (Note also that there's no meaningful difference between `*ptr++;` and `ptr++;`, since the result of `*` is ignored anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be aware of the difference of the following two data types (exact position of the '*'):

```
char const *variable_1;
char *const variable_2;
```

"variable_1" is a pointer to a read-only byte. However "variable_1" itself is not read-only.

"variable_2" is a read-only pointer to a byte. However the byte it points to is not read-only.

This means:

```
variable_1 = &xxx; // OK
variable_2 = &xxx; // Error
*variable_1 = yyy; // Error
*variable_2 = yyy; // OK
```

Now the meaning of the two types above is the following one:

```
const BYTE *   ==   BYTE const *
const LPBYTE   ==   BYTE * const
```

Answer (score 1):

`const LPBYTE` is a constant pointer to a byte and not pointer to a `const byte`. You just have to be aware of `*` position

Comment: The exact definitions are [`typedef BYTE far *LPBYTE;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `typedef unsigned char BYTE;`. But I don't see, how this answers the OP's question in particular?

Comment: Well, the solution is not to use these will typedefs and if you mean const unsigned char* then write it so!

Comment: @Quest I did it before i asked the question, but what i didn't understand is why "const LPBYTE" isn't considered as "const BYTE *".

Comment: there is a lot of pre-defined const pointers like LPCSTR that you can use

Comment: Another question: if const LPBYTE is a constant pointer to a byte doesn't that mean i can change the value of that byte ?

Comment: I thought *d++ increment the value but it increments the pointer !

Comment: int * const Value = 20;
*Value = 25;    //this should work

Comment: @Quest You really should try to improve the content of your answer. I have the feeling, it was a _'premature'_ accept ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: @Quest You mean, you can't edit right now?